# Intellisense cannot infer type from extension method

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, intellisense

The example below compiles successfully.
The compiler can infer the type of e (Customer)
My question is  why Intellisense cannot do the same?
When I type **customer.SetValue(** it correctly shows that the method expects

```
 Expression<Func<Customer, TProperty>>
```

but when I type **e => e.** it cannot understand that e is a Customer

**Is this expected or is it a bug?**

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplicationExpressionTree
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer.SetValue(e => e.Age, 10);
            customer.SetValue(e => e.Name, "TheName");
            //type here
         }
     }

     public static class Extentions
     {
        public static void SetValue<TEntity, TProperty>(this TEntity instance, Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> expression, TProperty newValue)
        {
            if (instance == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException();

            var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
            var property = (PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member;

            property.SetValue(instance, newValue, null);
        }
    } 
    public class Customer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
         public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm using VS 2015 ,.NET 4.6.1

**Update**
It is not related to Expression<> ,the method can change to

```
public static void SetValue<TEntity, TProperty>(this TEntity instance, Func<TEntity, TProperty> expression, TProperty newValue)
```

**Update 2**
I can reproduce it with

- VS 2015 Enterprise
- VS 2015 Community Edition

It seems to be working in (Haven't tested other versions)

- VS 2013 Ultimate
- VS 2013 Premium

Comment: I've had this happen a couple of times, about once every other week. Closing and reopening VS usually fixes it for me, but it is still annoying.

Comment: Im sure some code has been omitted to keep the question small, but can I ask the purpose of an extension to set the properties?

Comment: Looks like a bug, probably something to do with Roslyn.

Comment: @Wobbles,No,this is the full example

Comment: @JRLambert I've restarted my VS/PC but I always have this problem.I'll open a bug report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've filed a bug report at [connect.microsoft.com](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2263258/vs-2015-intellisense-cannot-infer-type-from-extention-method)

Answer (score 0):

> Is this expected or is it a bug?

It is neither really.

While Intellisense is there to help you as much as possible, it has never claimed to properly parse every single declaration in your code. This has traditionally been more of an issue with C++ and its complicated macro-based declarations, but every now and then you'll run into issues in C# too.

You can open a Connect issue over this if you want, but other than that it's something you can easily live with so don't expect too fast a response (think 2017 rather than 2015 update 2).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Blindy but since it works in previous editions I think it's a bug