# Open generic type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: c#, .net, generics, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

*In this question, when mentioning the compiler, I'm actually referring to the **Roslyn** compiler. The problem arises when using **IntelliSense**, which is presumed to be the same compiler.*

For demonstration purposes and completeness, the following classes are used (*using Visual Studio 2015 with C# 6.0 and .NET 4.6.1*):

```
public class A
{
    public IEnumerable<B> B { get; set; }
}
public class B
{
    public IEnumerable<C> C { get; set; }
}
public class C { }
public class Helper<T> { }
```

Behold the following extension method:

```
public static void FooBar<T1, T2>(
    this Helper<IEnumerable<T1>> helper,
    Expression<Func<T1, IEnumerable<T2>>> expression) { ... }
```

The compiler is able to infer it while consuming like this:

```
Helper<IEnumerable<B>> helper = ...;
helper.FooBar(l => l.C); //T1 is B and T2 is C
```

Also behold this overloaded extension method:

```
public static void FooBar<T1, T2, T3>(
    this Helper<T1> helper,
    Expression<Func<T1, IEnumerable<T2>>> expression1,
    Expression<Func<T2, IEnumerable<T3>>> expression2) { ... }
```

The compiler is **NOT** able to infer `T1` when typing it like this:

```
Helper<A> helper = ...;
helper.FooBar(l => l. //compiler/IntelliSense cannot infer that T1 is A
```

This screenshot example will describe more of what I mean with *not able to infer*:
[image]

Also I'm getting this error message when hovering over the extension method with my mouse (*I've replaced the `<` and `>` characters with `[` and `]` respectively, because StackOverflow cannot format those in a quote*):

> The type arguments for method 'FooBar[T1,T2](this Helper[IEnumerable[T1]], Expression[Func[T1, IEnumerable[T2]]])' cannot be inferred
>   from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

But when completing it *manually* like this:

```
helper.FooBar(l => l.B, l => l.C); //compiler infers that T1 is A, T2 is B and T3 is C
```

the compiler is happy.

Why can't the compiler/IntelliSense (*or the autocomplete feature of Visual Studio*) figure out `T1` and wants me to specify the type arguments explicitly when I start typing?

**Note** that if I omit `IEnumerable<>` everywhere in my examples, the compiler can happily infer everything while typing.
The compiler is also happy after you manually type in `l => l.B`. It then knows `T1` is `A`, so you can express the last argument *with* the help of IntelliSense.

Comment: when you say "compiler cannot infer that T1 is A" you actually mean the IDE's auto completion feature, right?

Comment: @TimPohlmann I've edited my question, concealing the irrelevant part. And yes, I mean IntelliSense auto completion feature does not work at that very specific moment.

Comment: One of the ideas behind the whole Roslyn project was to have one single compiler that both compiled the code and ran in IntelliSense. For some way however, IntelliSense is a little different than compiling stuff (I think more information is needed). So we still have some cases where IntelliSense just bails our, while code still happily compiles :-(

Comment: @Steven so are you proposing that this is actually a bug in IntelliSense?

Comment: I would more say it is a limitation 'by design' :)

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect here? The kind of "It has not been implemented because there is too much nesting and it's rarely a use case"? Or "Roslyn wasn't optimized to understand incomplete code and this one had been left out"? What do you do if you get such an answer?

Comment: @StefanSteinegger I expect a **confirmation** from experts on if this is a legit bug, or that this is an *intentional* limited feature by design.

Comment: I had a similar problem  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883559/intellisense-cannot-infer-type-from-extention-method 

I've created a bug report https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2263258/vs-2015-intellisense-cannot-infer-type-from-extention-method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, everything is working as expected for me in **VS2013**:

Your first case:

[image]

Your second case:

[image]

I'm starting to type the `l.` and IntelliSense shows me that `l` has a property `B` that can be used. So if I'm right and it **infers correctly** in **VS2013** whereas it **doesn't infer** in **VS2015**, then it's definitely a bug in **VS2015** IntelliSense that can be reported to Microsoft.

Comment: You are using the first overload (the one with `<T1, T2>` as open generic type arguments). This **does** work in **VS2015** (as I've mentioned in my question). The problem was that the second overload (the one with `<T1, T2, T3>`) didn't work in **VS2015**. Does that work in **VS2013**? Could you provide a screenshot if it *does* work in **VS2013**?

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand what's your problem is, but for me it shows hints correctly for both `Helper<A>` and `Helper<IEnumerable<A>>` regardless number of expressions. Please check the videos: 1) http://take.ms/Okfxx 2) http://take.ms/c5YZB However, if you would specify `Helper<A>` in the extension method and `Helper<IEnumerable<A>>` in your method it will think that `A` is `IEnumerable<A>` so won't show you the hint unless you take `First()` or something.

Comment: In the screenshot you provided, you are using the *first* extension method (since it's `Helper<IEnumerable<T>>`). So I'm asking you if the *second* extension method also works in **VS2013** (using `FooBar` with `Helper<T>`). If it works, then could you provide a screenshot proving that it works on the second extension method (the overload).

Comment: Yes, I've got that. Could you check my videos please?

Comment: I see, I can confirm that you are using the *second* extension method in **VS2013** (as I've described that that's the problem in my question). And it seems that *IntelliSense* for **VS2013** can infer the types while typing, whereas *IntelliSense* for **VS2015** cannot. So the question remains that if this is indeed a **bug**, or an **intentional** missing feature by **design**?

Comment: Well, if IntelliSense **suggests** you the right property in the **VS2013** and **doesn't suggest** in **VS2015** when **it should**, especially if you tell that it **allows** you to compile **after** you finish typing, but doesn't help **while** you're typing, then it sounds like an obvious bug for me. I don't see any reasons to make such uncomfortable and confusing behavior intentionally. Of course I may be wrong but such "improvement" would seem very weird for me.

Comment: I agree. As Steven said in the comments for my question: *For some way however, IntelliSense is a little different than compiling stuff (I think more information is needed)*. Since this is the **Roslyn** compiler in action. I'll wait until I can get an official confirmation. If not your answer will be marked as answered. After that I'll report it to Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

I found your question interesting and since I'm using VS 2015 I thought I could try it too. I got the same error as you did, so i guess it can be a VS bug, since in other versions it is working properly.

Here is my error:

[image]

And I also get *No suggestions* on CTRL + SPACE.

**EDIT:**

A similar bug can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883559/intellisense-cannot-infer-type-from-extention-method).

So, since in older versions of VS this works, then this is the reason why it can be considered a bug.

Answer (score 2):

As I said I had the [same problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883559/intellisense-cannot-infer-type-from-extention-method)   (And [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2263258/vs-2015-intellisense-cannot-infer-type-from-extention-method) is the bug report)
It is not related to Expressions or IEnumerable.
Here is a simplified example

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplicationExpressionTree
{

    public static class Extentions
    {
        static void Main() { }
        static void AMethod(string[] args)
        {
            SetValue(new Customer(), e => e.Name   /*type here */, "TheName");

        }

        public static void SetValue<TEntity, TProperty>(TEntity instance, Func<TEntity, TProperty> expression, TProperty newValue)
        {

        }
    }
    public class Customer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**I just noticed that if you remove the 3rd argument from the method it works !!!**

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplicationExpressionTree
{

    public static class Extentions
    {
        static void Main() { }
        static void AMethod(string[] args)
        {
            SetValue(new Customer(), e => e.Name   /*type here */);

        }

        public static void SetValue<TEntity, TProperty>(TEntity instance, Func<TEntity, TProperty> expression)
        {

        }
    }
    public class Customer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So if you are very lucky you might be able to fix your current example by tweaking your parameters.
If not,you'll just have to wait for MS to fix it...